# Angular fire fetching

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a code for working with upcoming events created by users. I have an option for users to search events by name and location. I use mergeMap from rxjs for that, but that is not working.
Here is my code:

upcoming.service.ts

```
searchByTag(text, type) {
    if (type == 'name') {
        return this.afs.collection('events').pipe(
            filter(data => data.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(text.toLowerCase() > -1))
        );
    } else if (type == 'location') {
        return this.afs.collection('events').pipe(
            filter(data => data.location.toLowerCase().indexOf(text.toLowerCase() > -1))
        )
    }
}
```

And upcoming.component.ts

```
val = new FormControl('');
events: any[] = [];

check() {
    of('name', 'location').pipe(mergeMap(type => {
        return this._upcoming.searchByTag(this.val.value, type);
    })).subscribe((data) => {
        this.events = data;
    })
}
```

Comment: your funtion takes 2 arg `searchByTag(text, type)` ... you're passing only one

Comment: Sorry, that was a mistake I made while I was creating the question

Comment: can you add a stackblitz for that ?

Comment: use `concatMap` instead of `mergeMap` and in your code you will see only result of 'location'

Comment: @bubbles I do not want to get results only of location. I want from both name and location. But it have not got any result

Comment: And Is the code from service good?

Comment: it seems to be good ... may be I can help you if you share your code on https://stackblitz.com/